# HIIT / HIT training with Heart Rate Monitor

Tags: cardio, heart-rate, hiit, interval-training, target-heart-rate

I understand using heart rate as a measure of how hard you train is difficult with HIIT (Compared to steady cardio).  So I am looking for programs in direction of HIIT/HIT where I can use it.

The purpose is:

1. To use work done combined with heart rate as a measure of fitness, so that I can make sure fitness level increases at a steady, moderate and significant rate.
2. (Less important) To have some measure  of intensity, or "how hard" single sessions are, and overall training load over time.

I imagine this can be sessions (Perhaps only one) of a few minutes at a high steady intensity or perhaps a fixed interval program on a elliptical machine or similar.

I am probably not in very good shape, so I should be able to progress with moderate intensity.

Suggestions for better terms are welcome

Comment: What is it you're asking about exactly, because you list HIT, HIIT, then mention moderate intensity cardio, all of which are different things.

Comment: A tag it hiit because I know using heart rate as a measure is a problem for those protocols.  Anyway the benefits of HIT starts at a low level. Also if I do just 5 minutes intense for example, the principles are similar to HIIT, even if I don't technically do intervals.

Comment: Just narrowed down the question.

Comment: ok, that reads much better now.

Comment: @Olav - I'm not a fan of using HR to measure effort. One, it's a downstream metric being used to gauge upstream effort, and it can vary wildly from day to day just depending on rest, hydration, whether you had that extra cup of coffee, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly not to be harsh, but I'd either commit to regular exercise or spend your time elsewhere.  This "plan" will not accomplish anything. ***It's a recipe to get no where doing anything in life.***

Why not **start of with 10 minutes every other day of light/moderate cardio** to develop the habit and **progress from there when you're ready**.

---

> I can promise you there are no shortcuts to getting healthy and
>   in-shape, but there are plenty of companies that would love to take
>   your money to tell you there are....

Get your mind right first and commit to your health without it you literally have nothing.

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIrT1eHs1b0**

Comment: My mind is already right, and habit is not an issue.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's more of an extended "don't do that" comment with no justification. If you could add *why* it's a recipe for going nowhere, that might help. Or a comparison of why steady state is better than HIIT/HIT?

Comment: When the reply was written it was addressing the original question (about doing the minimum), which has since been edited.  I can post fitness program retention rates, success determinants etc..  But simply applying the originally posted mindset to say a new job it's rather obvious why it won't last.

Comment: It was not very relevant as an answer even then.  If you think it is  something wrong with the question and its premisses you should post a comment.  Like it stands it just looks like you are promoting something.  You should delete it.

Comment: I have no problem with deleting it and you're free to do so, however I feel the mental side of working out (and discipline it takes) is often misunderstood and overlooked.  Would love to know what I'm promoting - David Goggins?  A Navy Seal who travels the world raising money for https://specialops.org/ (I'm seriously really curious what you believe I'm promoting)